# Multiple/bulk delete in react + redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a data grid that allows multiple selection and deletion feature. I have a delete endpoint from my api;

`DELETE http://localhost:8888/api/audit/id`

And this is the action creator;

```
export function deleteAudit(audits, callback) {
    let count = 0;
    console.log("selected audits", audits);

    const deleteItem = (auditId) => {
        console.log("deleting..", auditId);

        const endpoint = `http://localhost:8888/api/audit/${auditId}`;
        const req = Axios.delete(endpoint, callback);
        return (dispatch) => {
            req.then(res => {
                if (res.status == HttpStatus.OK) {
                    console.log("deleted", auditId);
                    count += 1;
                    if (audits[count] != null) {
                        deleteItem(audits[count]);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("all deleted heading to callback");
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            });
            dispatch({type:DELETE_AUDIT, payload: audits});
        }
    }
    deleteItem(audits[count]);
}
```

As my endpoint just allows one item deletion at a time, I used a recursive function to make calls successively. However, this ain't work properly when ignore using async(thunk) approach, it was not refreshing list with new state. 
After adding the thunk dispatch method it only deletes the first selection, so I get completely lost. What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems you need to dispatch(deleteItem(audits[count]))

Comment: @iofjuupasli so how will reducer know the type? Can you show how to implement, i didn't get it?

Comment: Seems like you use axios. Have you tried with axios.all instead of normal iteration?

Comment: @ThoVu yep, i am using axios, i am not aware axios features, let me check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I didn't import the `redux-thunk` package, after importing it, as @Tho Vu pointing out on axios, I have changed my code as follows;

```
export const deleteAudit = (audits, callback) => {

    const request = axios.all(_.map(audits, (audit) => 
    {   
        deleteItem(audit);
    }));
    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(axios.spread((a, f) => {
            dispatch({type:DELETE_AUDIT, payload:audits});
        })).then(() => {
            callback();
        });
    }
}
function deleteItem(id) {
    const endpoint = `http://localhost:8888/api/audit/${id}`;
    return axios.delete(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: please send all your IDs in one batch to be deleted all together in one query. your answer is correct to your question; However,  this is not an efficient approach to send delete requests one by one. this is exhausting.