# Axios delete method with a payload

Tags: javascript, axios

Im using axios on my react app to send a delete request, I need to send an id list as payload but it returns "415 Unsupported Media Type".

Here's my code:

```
const deviceData = ["31234"];

axios.delete(url, { data: deviceData }).then(res => {
  if (res.status === 200) {
    const pagination = { ...this.state.pagination };
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      data: res.data.data.devices,
      pagination
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: the problem only with delete method ?

Comment: @RapSherlock Yes

Comment: can you try to debug your request in back-end ?

Comment: @RapSherlock request is tested in postman and its working.

Answer (score 17):

`axiox.delete` does support a request body. It accepts two parameters: `url` and optional `config`. You can use `config.data` to set the response body as follows:

```
axios.delete(url, { data: { foo: "bar" } });
```

See here to more information: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897#issuecomment-343715381

Or you can try to set header with: 'Content-Type': `'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

```
const deviceData = ["31234"];

axios.delete(url,
  { headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'} },
  { data: { deviceData: deviceData } }).then(res => {
  if (res.status === 200) {
    const pagination = { ...this.state.pagination };
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      data: res.data.data.devices,
      pagination
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: See again the way that I send data to server `{ data: { deviceData: deviceData } }`.
Hope it helps !

Comment: are you sending multiple ids in your function ??

Comment: @Hardevgun Yes, Its an array of ids. Ex ["id1","id2","id3"]

Comment: @SNoV refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495292/multiple-bulk-delete-in-react-redux. hope this will help you.